# Using I2C or SPI device via Linux Userspace I/O driver?

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, spi, userspace

Is [Linux Userspace I/O](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/uio-howto.html) driver can support to use for a I2C or SPI device?

For example in case of use in an SoC like an i.MX or Zynq, is it possible to use UIO for I2C or SPI? Can be probed an I2C or SPI sensor/IC as `dev/uioX` device which is able to `mmap()` and also use some GPIO based interrupt?

In the device tree, is it possibble to use for example to make an UIO device on I2C bus on address 0x40?

```dts
&i2c1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c1>;
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    status = "okay";

    acc_sensor_0: acc_sensor@0x40 {
        reg = <0x40 0x100>;
        compatible = "generic-uio";
        linux,uio-name = "my_acc_sensor_0";
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Linux Userspace I/O driver can support to use for a I2C or SPI device?

No.
I2C and SPI are busses, and have a master controller and slave devices.
It's the master controller that is connected to, and therefore directly controlled (i.e. written to and read from) by the CPU. Any I/O with a slave device on the bus must be performed through the master controller. One abnormal exception is an interrupt; a slave device could generate an interrupt to the CPU, which is then handled by the slave device's driver.

Your question is ambiguous; to what exactly are you referring by "*I2C or SPI device*"?

If you meant a *slave* device, then you seem to be unaware that such a slave device is not accessed directly by the CPU. A slave device would have registers that are only accessed through the bus. Those registers would not be assigned any address in the SoC physical address space. Hence memory mapping of slave device registers by the CPU is impossible. An I2C or SPI slave device would not be a suitable candidate for Linux Userspace I/O driver.

An I2C slave device can be controlled from userspace using **i2c-dev**.
Study [Documentation/i2c/dev-interface.rst](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface.rst).

An SPI slave device can be controlled from userspace using **spidev**.
Study [Documentation/spi/spidev.rst](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/spi/spidev.rst).

---

An I2C or SPI master controller would not make a good candidate for a Linux Userspace I/O driver. An SPI master controller never has a userspace interface (e.g. a device node in the **/dev/** directory) even when it has a kernel driver.

---

Study [Introduction to I2C and SPI both in-kernel and in user space.](https://elinux.org/images/1/1e/I2C-SPI-ELC-2020.pdf)

Comment: Do you think should be it possible to make a fake `mmap()` fileoperation for i2c or spi userspace device driver and somehow get this feature work in a wrapper?

My goal is to use the memory of I2C or SPI sensors and ICs like it can driectly read/write a memory mapped I/O by a CPU.

Comment: A lot of things are possible, but not reasonable. Why emulate a specific hardware interface when that device could be EOL and obsolete next week? You seem to be putting thought and effort into the wrong goals. If you're going to add another layer of code, then add a layer of abstraction (e.g. a HAL) (for future portability) rather than a pseudo-hardware interface.

Comment: All of sensors like temperature, accelerometter, humadity and so on just a simple external/virtual register map in SW point of view in an I2C address or SPI chipselect, more over they have GPIO based interrupt connection sometime. So it means it optimal to use them as an UIO device or a memory mapped I/O device in Linux. Userspace SW developing could more standard to use an emulated `mmap()` for them, rather then IIO subsystem. It can be useful for sensors which has no IIO support in Linux, EOL is not relevant in this use case.